# How can I publish .net core solution

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a .Net Core web application that has two .Net Core class project dependencies in the same solution.

The scaffold structure of the project solution is as follows.

**MyProject.sln**

1. MyProject.Data
2. MyProject.Entity
3. MyProject.WebUI

I want to publish this solution in my web hosting but the publish option only appears on the WebUI does not appear on the solution.

How can I solve this ?

Comment: I'm not _entirely_ sure I understand your problem, but if you publish `MyProject.WebUI` and it has references to the other two, then those two will be included in the published assets for the first.

Comment: You can't publish a solution as it's possible/likely that there are multiple applications contained within it that would need publishing/deploying separately.

Comment: @ADyson 
Thank you very much, I thought I should publish three projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the UI project has a dependency (i.e. a reference) to the other two projects, then when you build the UI project (which will happen at publish time, if you don't do it separately beforehand), the other two projects will be compiled into DLL files and the resulting DLLs will be added to the build of the UI project automatically. This is how all .NET programs work.

So yes it's logical that you can only publish the UI project - the other two, being simple class libraries, would be no use on their own anyway, so it makes no sense to be able to publish them separately. You can only publish something which can actually be executed.

Comment: I agreed with your answer before I moved to .Net Core (VS2019) and found that (a) you can "Publish" a simple class library project, and (b) I cant publish my primary MVC app project without manually publishing the class library project first (I get an error during publish otherwise) -- which is very frustrating and seems like something is configured wrong. Any idea what might cause that behavior? The class library also generating a .nuget file although that build option is NOT ticked.

Comment: @Jimbo you still can't publish a _Solution_ in .NET Core / VS2019, which is what the question is asking about. That has never been possible in any version. If you have a problem with publishing your app, you should ask a new proper question about it and provide full details including all error messages etc, then the whole community can help. I don't think what you've described is especially relevant to this post anyway.